# Apt-get install - hash sum mismatch for 16.04 but not for 17.10

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, docker

I'm using Docker and what I try to do is running:

```
# Base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update packages list and system
RUN apt-get -y update;
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Allow to use add-apt-repository command
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common locales poppler-utils
```

But somehow on my Mac (on Windows it's fine) I'm getting strange errors:

- Hash Sum mismatch
- Writing more data than expected
- Failed to fetch ... 501 Not Implemented

However when I change 16.04 to 17.10 most errors disappear and my build go further but finally I also get for example:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+3.0/gtk-update-icon-cache_3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (10314 != 27564). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:f229acedb2cc946ff64a418245d10ea1166f0f8efaecf64fb59fae3d7f388c06
    - SHA1:675dbd8cf9818e3b277d33f762c249f6b7ecf685 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:934e1f67f0589a0b283c883fd21340f9 [weak]
    - Filesize:27564 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is there any reasonable explanation for this or maybe this is MacOS/Docker for Mac issue? As I said on Windows (in same network) I'm not getting such problem at all.

Comment: Just an FYI, but this tends to happen sometimes when the archives in the middle of a sync or something, and the hash sums are not completely updated yet on the remote.  As the error says, a mirror sync is possibly in progress.